# active low reset in Port Mapping

Tags: vhdl, reset, fpga

So when port mapping components on a "top file", is it possible to invert the reset input when port mapping it such as in the following example?

Assuming top file code is:

```
        entity topfile is
        port(
              clk : in std_logic;
              reset : in std_logic
              --Other input and outputs
                );


         architecture arch of topfile is
         begin

          c1: entity work.component1(behavioral)
          port map(
                    clk => clk,
                    reset => not reset,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                     );
          c2: entity work.component2(behavioral)
          port map(
                    clk => clk,
                    reset => not reset,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                     );


               end arch;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can, but you have to be using VHDL 2008. Previous to VHDL 2008, so called *expressions in port maps* were not allowed.

Do not take the decision to use VHDL 2008 lightly. Not all tools support VHDL 2008 and, even if you discover that all the tools that you currently use do support it, can you be sure that any tool you might wish to switch to in future will also support it?

Given the advantage of using VHDL 2008 to solve this specific problem is marginal, I would recommend using a dummy signal like this:

```
    entity topfile is
    port(
          clk : in std_logic;
          reset : in std_logic
          --Other input and outputs
            );


     architecture arch of topfile is
          signal resetn : std_logic
     begin

     resetn <= not reset;

      c1: entity work.component1(behavioral)
      port map(
                clk => clk,
                reset => resetn,
                .
                .
                .
                 );
      c2: entity work.component2(behavioral)
      port map(
                clk => clk,
                reset => resetn,
                .
                .
                .
                 );
```

Expressions in port maps add an extra delta delay, so the above will simulate *exactly* the same as your original code.

Answer (score 1):

As Matthew points out, *expressions* are not allowed in port maps pre-2008, but *conversion functions* are supported pre-2008, at least by Vivado, ISE, and ModelSim. You can write a simple `invert` function and put it in a package that gets `use`d in your other source files. Something like this:

```
function invert (input : std_logic) return std_logic is
begin
  return not input;
end function;
```

You can then use `reset => invert(reset),` in your port map, without requiring VHDL2008 support in your tools. This is still pretty readable, without using any 'extra' signals.

---

On a related note, I would suggest against using active low internal signals in an FPGA. Clock enables and resets for physical blocks in the device typically are not active low, so writing them as active low can result in extra inversion logic.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. As long as the type and length of the 'manipulated' signal matches the port.